# How to autostart apps in OS X as a different user

Tags: bash, mac-osx, cron, startup, couchdb

I am playing with CouchDB and whenever I do, I first have to issue

```
sudo couchdb -i -u couchdb couchdb -b
```

This starts CouchDB as the user couchdb, group couchdb. I then also have to enter my password again (I am admin but still need to, when doing a `sudo`) and all is fine.

How do I run CouchDB or anything similar at startup? Anytime anyone logs in, without any user interaction in OS X?

Answer (score 4):

You want to check out writing a [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) plist for CouchDB.

Specifically, it has fields for UserName and GroupName which provide the functionality you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Login scripts run with root permissions when anyone logs in. It would remove the need to use sudo.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420

Comment: Use launchd instead. It's hairy, but it works better for managing the startup of system wide programs like DB's or servers